# Sufficient conditions for $3\times 3$ matrix to be positive definite/semidefinite

Tags: matrices, inverse, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have a matrix 
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b_{12} & b_{13}\\
b_{21} & 0 & b_{23}\\
b_{31} & b_{32} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $b_{ij}<0$ $\forall i,j$. $B$ is not symmetric.

Could you suggest some sufficient conditions (possibly easily checkable) for $B$ to be positive definite or positive semidefinite?

Comment: Such matrix does not exist. Note that the first leading principal minor $-b_{21}b_{12}<0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SC Maree pointed out, the term "positive (semi-)definite" only applies to symmetric matrices.

But you might be interested in knowing whether $x^T B x \ge 0$ for all vectors $x$.
Suppose this is true.
Then in particular:
$$
0 \le (1,1,0)^T B\, (1,1,0) = b_{12}+b_{21},
$$
and
$$
0 \le (1,-1,0)^TB\,(1,-1,0) = - (b_{12}+b_{21}),
$$
hence $b_{12} = - b_{21}.$
This contradicts your assumption that $b_{ij} < 0$ for all $i,j$.

*Remark:* Considering the vectors $(1,0,1), (1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,1), (0,1,-1)$ also shows $b_{13} = - b_{31}$ and $b_{23} = - b_{32}.$ 
Hence for a three-dimensional matrix $B$ with zero diagonal to satisfy $x^T B x \ge 0$ for all $x$, it is necessary that 
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b_{12} & b_{13} \\ - b_{12} & 0 & b_{23} \\ - b_{13} & - b_{23} & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can check that in this case $x^T B x = 0$ for all $x$. So the condition is also sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

For a symmetric matrix $B$, it follows from [Sylverster's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) that this is not possible. Positive definiteness requires that $b_{11} > 0$. The second leading principal minor is $-b_{21}b_{21} < 0,$ thus the matrix is also not positive semi-definite.

For non-symmetric matrices $B$, there is no general agreement on what a "positive definite non-symmetric matrix" is.